# Visual C++ String Parsing

Tags: string, parsing, visual-c++

I wrote my own terminal program that reads from the serial port to read data from a microcontroller. Data is presented as follows:

> 0C82949>0D23949>0A75249> etc...

These are ASCII. Some things to note are that all elements start with >_0xx which is the header  where xx is some chars such as >0C8 or >0D2 etc... this tells me what the rest of the data is such as if >0C8 is the speed of the car then 2949 holds the actual speed. The microcontroller writes the data really fast so at one time i can see 40 elements at a time. I want to quickly search this for an ">0C8" entry and only print out ">0C82949" out of the bunch:

an example if i only want 0D2:

Read from Serial Port: >0C82949>0D23949>0A75249>
Output: 0D23949

would anyone know how to do this?? I am aware that since it is so fast i would have to create threads which i can do, i am just not sure how to approach this issue for parsing. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

**I am using Visual C++**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse the data and divide it on each `>` character. Then create separate strings. For each string, just search for desired substring. You may use `strstr` or `CString::Find` or `string::find`.
There is no need to create separate thread - the search operation is quite trivial and won't take much of CPU.